# How to limit name of EC2 Instances created through IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to limit my IAM role so I can only start/stop EC2 instances with a certain Tag Name
Presumably this is a common use case to make sure you don't start/stop/delete the wrong EC2 instance!

I've created this role:

```
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": [
                "InstanceName",
                "InstanceName_Two"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

(based on the example at https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/1928 )

And I'm trying to create an instance via boto3 with:

```
{'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'InstanceName'} }
```

But I get the error
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation`

It works fine without adding in the "ec2:ResourceTag/Name" condition

How do I create a role that can only start/stop EC2 instances with a specific name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}` as per the documentation [Condition keys for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-aws_ResourceTag___TagKey_)

[ResourceTag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-resourcetag) Global Condition.

The below policy works fine.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": [
                        "InstanceName",
                        "InstanceName_Two"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Between I am not sure why you need `ec2:RunInstances` permission even when you mentioned

> only start/stop EC2 instances with a certain Tag Name